# Options for current sensing for a 230V , 100 W boost PFC circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, instrumentation-amplifier, power-factor-correction, simulink

So I have the following boost PFC circuit:
[image]

I wish to sense the inductor current. My first thought was using shunt with instrumentation amplifiers, but the issue is total voltage across the inductor is around 400V and no instrumentation amplifier has that high of a common mode voltage range. All the design articles seem to use readymade controllers with integrated current sensing whereas I will be using DSPACE so I cannot use controller ICs. What are my options in this case? This is the current waveform I wish to sense:

[image]

And this is the inductor voltage:
[image]

Comment: There is no excuse for that bridge rectifier being shown as it is.

Comment: For a low-power PFC like this one, you could even avoid sensing the current using a constant \$t_{on}\$ approach and operate the circuit in quasi-resonant mode with an extra winding on the inductor. For a real industrial project, you would need to sense the current cycle-by-cycle as recommended by *bobflux* but for experimental purposes, it may be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

On the high side you can use a Hall effect sensor. This may reduce bandwidth and add poles, depending on what sensor you use.

But you can also place a current sense resistor on the low side: either in the MOSFET source if you're only interested in current when the FET is on, or on the ground wire if you want to measure it all the time. Unless the top diode is conducting, current in the ground wire is the same as inductor current. But if the sense circuit's ground is at the FET source (and output ground), and the sense resistor is on the ground wire, then measured voltage on the sense resistor will be negative, so keep this in mind while choosing the amplifier.

Comment: Be certain that high side hall sensor can NEVER be destroyed thermally under overload.
 This can lead to loss of isolation with subsequent excitement. I found :-)

Comment: I'd be worried about the inrush current into that 800µF cap... but that will also go through the shunt resistor if it's in the ground line, which means it should be able to withstand it...

Comment: A 800-µF capacitor is not an adequate value for a 100-W PFC anyway and is way oversized or *overkill* as Lemmy would have said : ) Looks like these are values thrown without calculation.

Comment: The PFC circuits I’ve seen in TVs use another winding on the inductor for current sense.